# R link error too many resource to handle

Tags: delphi, linker, linker-errors, embedded-resource, delphi-2007

I have a large project(single exe) having three thousand pas files and almost two thousand dfms. It also contains several resource strings and image lists.

This project was working very fine and was enhancing this again and again for several modules as per user requirement. I cannot split this application to multiple exes because of several reasons.
My customer is willing to buy that much hardware for supporting it.

Now recently i started getting "R link error- too many resources to handle" error when i compile after adding a new form in to the project. As a work around what i did is, i made some of the resourcestring in to constants. so again project started compiling like before. ie without any error. now whenever i need to add a new form (resource) i will make some of the resourcestring to constants. now there are no more resourcestrings remains in my project. so i am almost struck now.

Could you help me to escape from this link error without splitting application.

Thanks in advance.
Basil

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about breaking it up into a .dll or package? It's not a separate exe, and things can be broken out into usable parts.

Or does the client only one one executable?

[Dll Example](http://www.delphi-central.com/formdll.aspx)

[BPL DLL differences](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/bpl_vs_dll.htm)

Comment: i already suggested this two option, sorry i ddnt mention it. bpl seems more acceptable but they are looking for some solution with the current implementation as believes its a delphi or windows bug.

Comment: why this limitation ? thats the question they are asking. because they are willing to support with any good hardware equipments.

Comment: Which version of Delphi are you using? Do you have a large .res file?

Comment: I am using Delphi 2007 . Only one resource file is using which is 2.65 KB size.

Comment: All DFM and DRC and RC files are resources as well.

Comment: That is not bug, that is limitation. The airplane cannot lift the all the tonnage, that a cargo train can move over the railway. But don't call this an airplane bug, it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Working with delphi 7 I had the same problem.
What partly fixed it was to replace the rlink32.dll from delphi 7 with a version of a more recent delphi.

Comment: Tried with latest rlink32.dll of Delphi XE2 now. No luck :-(