# Delphi 7 throws an error: RLINK32 Too many resources to handle

Tags: delphi, compilation, resources, delphi-7, linker-errors

Delphi 7 has decided that it no longer want to cooperate. I was working on a relatively small project and was all but finished, but as I chose an icon for the exe-file the program threw this error: RLINK32 Too many resources to handle.

Now it throws that error even on a completely empty form whenever I try to compile it.

Comment: If it happens on an empty new fresh project then the RLINK32.dll has been corrupted, have you tried simply reinstalling Delphi?

Comment: Similar question, [`R link error too many resource to handle`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16329646/576719).

Comment: I will try to reinstall, thank you.

Comment: If the Delphi 7 linker won't link your resource, and that does sometimes happen, then link the resource as a post-processing step

Comment: Deletion of the project res file might solve the problem (Delphi will rebuild it). I have heard that res files of 3th-party components like Virtual Treeview may cause it as well. Check the res files for unusal size.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record:
Today I ran into this error (also using Delphi 7). I was editing the DFM directly/manually (for my project is a pure WinApi application).
I got the error when assigning an **empty string** to a property (inside the DFM file).

```
Caption = ''
```

Obviously, the **RLINK32 error** was gone as soon as I removed the infamous **empty string** (which the compiler doesn't like), or after changing the value to a non-empty string.